# Solr explain is returned with empty keys

Tags: solr, similarity, explain

While making a search request via solr it is possible to see the score explanation. Solr returns explanations for all the returned documents. But the explanation containes empty keys:

> "explain":{
>         "":"qwerrewerwe",
>         "":"qwrerfegregrh"...

I guess that the key must contain something like the document id but it doesn't. Why can it happen or is it normal solr behaviour? Any help would be appreciated.

Currently I use 
6.4.0, SchemaSimilarityFactory and I tried using custom similaruty with the same result.

The query looks like this:

> products/select?debugQuery=on&indent=on&wt=json&fl=Code:GenericCode,*,score&rows=20&q=Name:((tea)^2) Description:((tea )) Keywords:((tea ))

Comment: which solr version you're using? could you're share the query you're using?

Comment: I updated the question